# Why hibernate flushes on select queries (EmptyInterceptor)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, readonly, interceptor, flush

I would like to understand a counter intuitive Hibernate behaviour I am seeing. I always thought that "flush" meant that hibernate had a data structure in-memory that has to be written to the DB. This is not what I am seeing.

I have created the following Interceptor:

```
public class FeedInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor
{
    @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator entities)
    {
          System.out.println("postFlush");          
    }
}
```

Registered it in my ApplicationContext

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="entityInterceptor">
      <bean class="interceptor.FeedInterceptor"/>
   </property>
</bean>
```

But, strange enough, I see "postFlush" written to the console for every row retrieved from the DB from my DAO:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Feed feed");
query.list();
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume Hibernate wouldn't flush the session, then you could have the following situation:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Pomario");
dao.create(p);
Person pomario = dao.findPersonByName("Pomario")
//pomario is null?
```

When finding a person by name, hibernate issues a select statement to the database. If it doesn't send the previous statements first, then the returned result might not be consistent with changes that have been done previously in the session, here the dababase hasn't received the create statement yet, so it returns an empty result set.

Comment: I would expect the just created Person to exist in some form of  cache (first/second-level) and that hibernate would be smart to  know that the dirty data has to be flushed before findPersonByName() is executed against the DB - opposed to every single invocation of findPersonByName(), which I see with query.list(). Could please comment on this?

Comment: You're right, it could detect that some unsave changes have to be flushed to the database, and then flush the hibernate session only when required. I didn't understand your question. It would be interesting to know if the flush happens before the select statement is issued, or after (you could set show_sql paramater for example). If you see "postFlush" appearing in the console after the statement then maybe it would mean the "flush" operation consists of issuing all pending statement to the database, the last one being the select statement you need to be executed when runing `query.list()`

Comment: It already has this optimization. If you persist or modify a Person, and execute a query which only uses the Foo entity, Hibernate won't flush before executing the query.